# file loader.cs not found in mvc Rpoject

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this error in my .net MVC project :

```
 File ....\SqlServerTypes\loader.cs not found.
```

Well the file exist but with an exlamation point and i can't open it.
Any help and thanks

Comment: Usually it means that project contains "reference" to the file but there is no file on file system. Did you check file existence via file explorer?

Comment: yeah I already checked that via file explorer and it doesn't exist.

Comment: please add screen shot of your visual studio -> solution explorer with error @Alexander is right at this moment.Please check reference files